# How do I extract a line matching a string and the next line?

Tags: string, perl, text-extraction

I have two files, namely `a.txt` and `b.txt`. My task is to search all the strings of `a.txt` in `b.txt`. If I have any match between the strings of `a.txt` and `b.txt`, then I want to print the line corresponding to that string and its next line from the file `b.txt`.

I have been trying the below mentioned code but the problem is that it is not printing anything. Can you please point me out the problem and suggest a way to solve this?

```
open fh,  "<", "b.txt" or die $!;
open fh1, "<", "a.txt" or die $!;

my $array1 = < fh>;
my $array2 = < fh1>;

while (my $array1 = < fh>) {
    if ($array1 =~ m/$array2/i) {
        print $array1;
        print scalar < fh>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
open  fh, "<", "b.txt" or die $!;
open  fh1, "<", "a.txt" or die $!;

while(my $item1 = <fh>)
{
    while(my $item2 = <fh1>)
    {
        if($item1 =~ m/$item2/i)
        {
            print $item1;
            print <fh>;
        }
    }

    seek fh1, 0, 0;
}

close fh;
close fh1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BSen, It works But once the 1st element of a.txt has been searched i want to print the matched data into another file. i.e. 1st element searched in a1.txt ,2nd element searched in a2.txt and hence forth. At present whith your help i am able to save all the elements in just one file.

Comment: Can you help me out to modify the code given by you,to do the task as mentioned in my above comment

Comment: If I do understand what you want, then add a variable outside of the loop, increment it at every match and open handle to new file (using variable to form name eg a1, a2 ...) then write to it and close it

Comment: here is what i tried with the code u suggested..                                                         ** open  fh, "<", "b.txt" or die $!; 
**open  fh1, "<", "a.txt" or die $!;  
**while(my $item1 = <fh>) {     
**while(my $item2 = <fh1>)     
**{         
**if($item1 =~ m/$item2/i)         
**{
**my $i =0; 
**{
**print fh2 $item1;
**open fh2, ">>", "c$i.txt";                                                **i++;          
**print <fh>;         
**}     
**}      
**seek fh1, 0, 0; 
**}  
**}
**close fh; 
**close fh1;
**close fh2; this isnt working.. so can u suggest me how to go about this

Comment: Not sure what you want to print to file, but try this http://pastebin.com/V2bHGJAF

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is obvious:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line1;
my $line2;
my $fh;
my $fh1;
my $counter;

open  $fh, "<", "b.txt" or die $!;
open  $fh1, "<", "a.txt" or die $!;

my @b = <$fh>;
my @a = <$fh1>;

for (@b)
{
    $line1 = $_;
    for (@a)
    {
        $line2 = $_;
        if ($line1 =~ /^$line2$/)
        {
            $counter++;
            open $outfile, ">", "a_${counter}.txt";
            print $outfile $line2;
            close $outfile;
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't really understand is what are you trying to do with `scalar`?

Comment: thank you very much Hameed.It works But once the 1st element of a.txt has been searched i want to print the matched data into another file. i.e. 1st element searched in a1.txt ,2nd element searched in a2.txt and hence forth. At present whith your help i am able to save all the elements in just one file

Comment: Does that mean you will have as many files as the number of matches?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response,..... Yes i will have as many files as the number of matches. If i have n elements in a.txt then b.txt will be searched for those n elements and if match is found for all the n elements then their will be n files. In my case the number may vary between 7-10 elements hence 7-10 files.

Comment: Start a counter, every time you get a match, increment the counter, open a file using the counter as part of file name `open my $outfile, ">", "a${counter}.txt"` and then write to it and close it.

Comment: This is what i want to do,but i am not able to print any file or generate any file mentioned by you.At persent I am not able to figure out the problem,I am trying to work on it.

Answer (score -1):

i can help you in getting two array of elements , i didt understand how u want to print the matched and next elements,

```
use Data::Dumper;
open(FH,  "<$file") or die "$!";
open(FH1,  "<$file1") or die "$!";
my @array1 ;
my @array2 ;


while(<FH>) {
    chomp($_);
    push @array1,$_;
}
while(<FH1>) {
    chomp($_);
    push @array2,$_;
}
close(FH);
close(FH1);
print Dumper(@array1);
print Dumper(@array2);
```